# How do I install Anthos on an Autopilot cluster without getting autogke-csr-limitation error?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, google-anthos, google-anthos-service-mesh

I am trying to install Anthos. I do this using the following command...

```
asmcli install -p project -l us-central1 -n earth-615 --managed --verbose --output_dir earth-615 --use_managed_cni --channel Rapid --enable-all
```

So I try to check it with

```
kubectl describe controlplanerevision asm-managed-rapid -n istio-system
```

It seems to be failing...

```
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2022-04-11T21:42:50Z
    Message:               The provisioning process has not completed successfully
    Reason:                NotProvisioned
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Reconciled
    Last Transition Time:  2022-04-11T21:42:50Z
    Message:               Provisioning has finished
    Reason:                ProvisioningFinished
    Status:                True
    Type:                  ProvisioningFinished
    Last Transition Time:  2022-04-11T21:42:50Z
    Message:               An error occurred reconciling CNI & MDP controller
    Reason:                ProvisioningFailed
    Status:                True
    Type:                  Stalled
Events:                    <none>
```

I check the docs for [status code here](https://cloud.google.com/service-mesh/docs/managed/configure-managed-anthos-service-mesh#stalled_codes) and I don't see that as an expected error code.

When I look at the log for `istio-asm-...` pod I see the following...

```
2022-04-12T12:22:47.328302Z error   retry attempts exceeded when creating csr request csr-workload-wbksbgm8zzp5w8tgx6
Error: failed to create discovery service: failed generating key and cert by kubernetes: unable to submit CSR request (). Error: admission webhook "gkepolicy.common-webhooks.networking.gke.io" denied the request: GKE Policy Controller rejected the request because it violates one or more policies: {"[denied by autogke-csr-limitation]":["CSR 'csr-workload-wbksbgm8zzp5w8tgx6' disallowed in Autopilot."]}
2022-04-12T12:22:47.328580Z error   failed to create discovery service: failed generating key and cert by kubernetes: unable to submit CSR request (). Error: admission webhook "gkepolicy.common-webhooks.networking.gke.io" denied the request: GKE Policy Controller rejected the request because it violates one or more policies: {"[denied by autogke-csr-limitation]":["CSR 'csr-workload-wbksbgm8zzp5w8tgx6' disallowed in Autopilot."]}
```

How do I install Anthos without getting the `autogke-csr-limitation` error?

Comment: Do you actually have any worker nodes in your cluster?  I assume you are installing ASM on a GKE cluster?

Comment: I do not have anything installed on the cluster besides ASM. I am just trying to set it up on a new cluster so I can get it working and try porting our Istio Gateways and Services. Yes it is a GKE autopilot cluster on rapid

Comment: Updated the text to be clearer given what I have learned

Comment: Which GKE version are you running?

Comment: @Jackie If your  issue is solved , can you please provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem @Jackie? Could you share?