# Can we install Anthos Service Mesh on google on-prem cloud edge cluster?

Tags: google-compute-engine

Trying to install ASM on premise GDCE servers but its failing and coming out after 5 retries.

```
/usr/local/bin/asmcli install --fleet_id grv-xyz  --kubeconfig xxx/xxx/.kube/config  --output_dir /home/piyush/testasm   --platform multicloud   --enable_all 
set 2 field(s) of setter "anthos.servicemesh.trustDomainAliases" to value "grv-1162.svc.id.goog"
namespace/istio-system labeled
asmcli: Installing validation webhook fix...
service/istiod created
asmcli: Installing ASM control plane...
asmcli: [WARNING]: Failed, retrying...(1 of 5)
```

When checked istio pod logs seeing below error.

```
kubectl get pods -n istio-system
NAME                                 READY   STATUS             RESTARTS      AGE
istiod-asm-1157-23-586f6658b-g4zkh   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6 (73s ago)   7m10s
istiod-asm-1157-23-586f6658b-vgxvn   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6 (86s ago)   7m25s


2024-01-08T19:38:24.032740Z info    done initializing workload trustBundle
2024-01-08T19:38:24.032754Z info    initializing Istiod DNS certificates host: istiod-asm-1157-23.istio-system.svc, custom host:
2024-01-08T19:38:24.032762Z info    Generating K8S-signed cert for [istiod-asm-1157-23.istio-system.svc istiod.istio-system.svc istiod-remote.istio-system.svc istio-pilot.istio-system.svc]
2024-01-08T19:38:24.333489Z error   retry attempts exceeded when creating csr request csr-workload-r9z598s2kgzg9m87kw
Error: failed to create discovery service: failed generating key and cert by kubernetes: unable to submit CSR request (). Error: admission webhook "gkepolicy.common-webhooks.networking.gke.io" denied the request: GKE Policy Controller rejected the request because it violates one or more policies: {"[denied by autogke-csr-limitation]":["CSR 'csr-workload-r9z598s2kgzg9m87kw' disallowed in Autopilot."]}
2024-01-08T19:38:24.333534Z error   failed to create discovery service: failed generating key and cert by kubernetes: unable to submit CSR request (). Error: admission webhook "gkepolicy.common-webhooks.networking.gke.io" denied the request: GKE Policy Controller rejected the request because it violates one or more policies: {"[denied by autogke-csr-limitation]":["CSR 'csr-workload-r9z598s2kgzg9m87kw' disallowed in Autopilot."]}
```

Not sure if ASM is supported on GDCE clusters.

Already opened ports 15014 & 15017 in firewall for istio.

Comment: Please format your post to help with readability. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1):

It is supported. Anthos Service Mesh (ASM) can be installed on Google on-prem cloud edge (GDCE) clusters. You can use this [document](https://cloud.google.com/service-mesh/docs/unified-install/install-anthos-service-mesh#on-premises_1) to install ASM.

But the autogke-csr-limitation issue that you are encountering has to do something with policy violation in GKE Autopilot which restricts the use of certain features. You can review the policies and limitations of Autopilot [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-security).

Here's another post regarding  autogke-csr-limitation

[How do I install Anthos on an Autopilot cluster without getting autogke-csr-limitation error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71834651/how-do-i-install-anthos-on-an-autopilot-cluster-without-getting-autogke-csr-limi)